# Get needed bitmap width and height to fit in base64 string

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I'm working on an Android app which takes a bitmap, converts it to a base64 string and sends it to a backend which saves it as a string.

The backend's size limit is about 1M, so I need to resize the bitmap locally before sending it to ensure the base64 string won't exceed that limit.

Is there any way, formula, etc to know what I must resize the bitmap to in order to achieve a base64 string of a given length?

I'm currently doing this recursively, but this obviously is not the best solution.

Snippet:

```
private void scaleImg(float scale) {
    int newWidth = (int)(bmp.getWidth() * scale);
    int newHeight = (int)(bmp.getHeight() * scale);

    bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    base64EncodedImg = PicUtils.convertBitmapToBase64String(bmp);
    base64EncodedImgLength = base64EncodedImg.length();

    if(base64EncodedImgLength > 1000000) {
        scaleImg(scale - 0.1f);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Base64 adds ~1.37x the number of bytes.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

You also have to account for the color bytes in your size calculation. You don't say how the image is encoded (PicUtils.convertBitmapToBase64String()?). i'll assume 32 bit color uncompressed (raw Android bitmap bytes).

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    Pair<Integer,Integer> size = fitSize((int)Math.pow(10, 6),bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, size.first, size.second, true);
    byte[] bytes = getBitmapBytes(bitmap);
    byte[] base64 = Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.i("bitmapscaletest", "base 64 size: " + base64.length);


  private Pair<Integer, Integer> fitSize(int size, int w, int h) {
    double scale = 1.0;
    while ((int)(w * h * 4 * 1.37) > size) {
      scale -= 0.001;
      w *= scale;
      h *= scale;
    }
    return new Pair<Integer,Integer>(w, h);
  }
```

This is better than what you had since it's not actually decoding / re-encoding the bitmap each iteration. This could be enhanced to do a sort of binary search. Make 0.001 smaller to get the size closer to 10^6.

Comment: This is helpful, however I would still need a recursive approach it seems, right?

Comment: Actually this isn't quite working. Using `float scale = MAX_IMG_SIZE_BASE64 / (5.48f * bmpWidth * bmpHeight);` and I'm getting a very small image. Could this be because of the encoding? How do I find what encoding is being used?

Comment: I'm using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);` previously in the code to get the actual bitmap.

Comment: what's the size in bytes of the base64 encoded data after applying the scale? when uncompressed in memory, a 640x480 image uses 1.2M.

Comment: you are right this doesn't work as you'd expect. s is correct, but it is a scaling of the number of bytes ... you need a scaling of the width and height. see updated answer.